# How to check all user abends with single if condition in JCL

Tags: jcl

How to check all user abend codes using single if condition in JCL?

Explanation: My job is abending with different user abends

[Reference](http://www.workers.com.br/manuais/53/html/tcp53/mu/mu-2.htm#40221).

Currently I am checking like this

```
//  IF (P535S040.RC > 0) THEN
```

It is checking for only return code,  but I need to check user abends also.

Answer (score 3):

According to the IBM [KnowledgeCenter](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/z/os/zos/library/bkserv/),

```
// IF ABEND THEN
```

...will check any abend in *any* previous step.

```
// IF stepname.ABEND THEN
```

...will check for any abend in `stepname`.

```
// IF (stepname.RC > 0 | stepname.ABEND) THEN
```

...will check for a return code > 0 or any abend in `stepname`.

The JCL reference is under z/OS MVS in the table of contents.

Comment: You can also use the old-fashioned COND=EVEN or COND=ONLY in place of IF statements. COND=EVEN runs the step, even if a prior step abended. COND=ONLY runs the step, only if a prior step abended.